# Adding new field on commerce email module in drupal

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-commerce

I am using the module commerce email http://drupal.org/project/commerce_email so as to sent an e-mail with the full order of the customer to my administrator email.Everything works fine.But in the mail it is sent only the title of the product the quantity and the price.I want to sent the brand of the product also.It seems that everything I did nothing worked so as to sent the brand.Anyone that uses the same module could help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am just looking at commerce email myself, and see that you asked this question quite a while ago ... but just in case somebody can find this useful, it seems to me that what you are getting from commerce email is the line item information of the product. THat being the case, if the brand info was in the line item you should be in good shape